# Reveal can't run on my Mac

Tags: osx-elcapitan

reveal can’t run normally on my mac ,the OS X is 10.11.1. When I click the reveal.app,it is like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evxKp.jpg):

would you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related question, not understanding chinese error messages of random OS X programs.

Answer (score 0):

I use the standard "Unarchiving Tool" built into OS X to unzip the Reveal,it works well.

ensure you use the standard "Unarchiving Tool" built into OS X to unzip the .zip file that your browser downloads. Don't use 3rd party Unzip/Unarchiving utilities.